# NgRx effect is not initialized when navigating back to module

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have a lazy loaded module that holds a state with forFeature provider, and that module holds effect that injected specifically to the module.

when I navigate to another route(another lazy loaded module), and go back to the module with the state, the effect is not triggered again as I expect.

**Effect**:

[image]
[image]

**OptimizationTabModule**:
[image]

Comment: Please post code rather than images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is is working as intended.
The `OnInit` is fired when the effect is registered (which is only once).

Comment: Its because the lazy loaded module is not loaded again?

Comment: Yea, correct. Once a module is loaded, it can't be "reloaded". Also for effects, once it's registed in a module, and then re-registered in a second module it would only invoke the OnInit the first time.